# How to InputStream Data from fileURLWithPath in Swift

Tags: swift, inputstream, filepath, progressdialog, outputstream

I still fairly new to Swift, so please forgive me lack of experience in explaining, but could someone please help me understand, if there is a way to InputStream/OutputStream a file from my directory with the code below.

```
let bundlePath = Bundle.main.bundlePath
let fileName = fileNames[0]
let filePath = bundlePath + "/" + fileName
let fileData = try! Data(contentsOf: URL(fileURLWithPath: filePath))
```

So, this would mean I need to InputStream/OutputStream fileData? My goal is to show this stream within a progress bar, however I would like to know if there is way to do this and how.

I have written this code below, can you please tell me how to connect this to the fileData?

```
if let aStream = (readStream as? InputStream) {
inputStream = aStream
}
inputStream.delegate = self
inputStream.schedule(in: RunLoop.current, forMode: .defaultRunLoopMode)
inputStream.open()
// Setup output stream.
if let aStream = (writeStream as? OutputStream) {
outputStream = aStream
}
outputStream.delegate = self
outputStream.schedule(in: RunLoop.current, forMode:.defaultRunLoopMode)
outputStream.open()

func stream(_ aStream: Stream, handle eventCode: Stream.Event) {
print("NSStreamEvent Streaming ")
switch eventCode {
    case [], .openCompleted, .errorOccurred, .endEncountered:
        break
    case .hasBytesAvailable:
        if (stream is InputStream) {
            print("Inside readStream")
        }
    case .hasSpaceAvailable:
        if (stream is OutputStream) {
            print("Inside writeStream")
        }
    default:
        break
 }
```

}

Comment: No, you need to create an `InputStream` instance from the URL, `schedule` the stream to the runloop, `open` the stream, `run` the runloop and handle the events. The progress can be controlled by the written bytes.

Comment: Please check me edit above.

Comment: You can create `InputStream` from `Data`, `URL` and `String`. Please read the [documentation](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/inputstream). And you have to implement the [delegate method](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/streamdelegate/1410079-stream) to handle the received events.

Comment: I've written the delegate method, I still not sure how to create the instance from the fileData URL, can I trouble you for some sort of example of this, as I have read the docs and still can't get my head around this, would really appreciate this? please check my edit above.